# Why Dart cannot check array bound in compile time?

Tags: dart

Even if I declare my list as fixed-length List, Dart cannot check array bound in compile time.

```
void main() {
  var fixed = List<int>(5);
  fixed[5000] = 3;           //Runtime error! 
}
```

I tested in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/). Why Dart cannot check array bound in compile time?